# SNORT not alerting to console

Tags: centos, snort

I'm trying to test snort 2.9.4 on CentOS 6.4 but cannot see any alerts on the console. I run it with the following command:

snort -i eth2 -c /etc/snort/snort.conf

eth2 is the interface connected to a span port. If I do a tcpdump on the interface I get lots and lots of data.

I have the following rules in local.rules:

```
alert icmp any any -> any any (msg: "ICMP Testing Rule"; sid:1000001; rev:1;)
alert tcp any any -> any 80 (msg: "TCP Testing Rule"; sid:1000002; rev:1;)
alert udp any any -> any any (msg: "UDP Testing Rule"; sid:1000003; rev:1;)
```

When I hit "control c" I get the following stats:

```
===============================================================================
Run time for packet processing was 817.54341 seconds
Snort processed 17555 packets.
Snort ran for 0 days 0 hours 13 minutes 37 seconds
   Pkts/min:         1350
   Pkts/sec:           21
===============================================================================
Packet I/O Totals:
   Received:        17610
   Analyzed:        17555 ( 99.688%)
    Dropped:           55 (  0.311%)
   Filtered:            0 (  0.000%)
Outstanding:           55 (  0.312%)
   Injected:            0
===============================================================================
Breakdown by protocol (includes rebuilt packets):
        Eth:        17599 (100.000%)
       VLAN:            0 (  0.000%)
        IP4:        17175 ( 97.591%)
       Frag:            0 (  0.000%)
       ICMP:           16 (  0.091%)
        UDP:          794 (  4.512%)
        TCP:        16365 ( 92.988%)
        IP6:           12 (  0.068%)
    IP6 Ext:           12 (  0.068%)
   IP6 Opts:            0 (  0.000%)
      Frag6:            0 (  0.000%)
      ICMP6:           12 (  0.068%)
       UDP6:            0 (  0.000%)
       TCP6:            0 (  0.000%)
     Teredo:           12 (  0.068%)
    ICMP-IP:            0 (  0.000%)
      EAPOL:            0 (  0.000%)
    IP4/IP4:            0 (  0.000%)
    IP4/IP6:            0 (  0.000%)
    IP6/IP4:            0 (  0.000%)
    IP6/IP6:            0 (  0.000%)
        GRE:            0 (  0.000%)
    GRE Eth:            0 (  0.000%)
   GRE VLAN:            0 (  0.000%)
    GRE IP4:            0 (  0.000%)
    GRE IP6:            0 (  0.000%)
GRE IP6 Ext:            0 (  0.000%)
   GRE PPTP:            0 (  0.000%)
    GRE ARP:            0 (  0.000%)
    GRE IPX:            0 (  0.000%)
   GRE Loop:            0 (  0.000%)
       MPLS:            0 (  0.000%)
        ARP:            3 (  0.017%)
        IPX:            0 (  0.000%)
   Eth Loop:            0 (  0.000%)
   Eth Disc:            0 (  0.000%)
   IP4 Disc:            0 (  0.000%)
   IP6 Disc:            0 (  0.000%)
   TCP Disc:            0 (  0.000%)
   UDP Disc:            0 (  0.000%)
  ICMP Disc:            0 (  0.000%)
All Discard:            0 (  0.000%)
      Other:          421 (  2.392%)
Bad Chk Sum:            0 (  0.000%)
    Bad TTL:            0 (  0.000%)
     S5 G 1:           11 (  0.063%)
     S5 G 2:           33 (  0.188%)
      Total:        17599
===============================================================================
Action Stats:
     Alerts:         4933 ( 28.030%)
     Logged:         4933 ( 28.030%)
     Passed:            0 (  0.000%)
Limits:
      Match:            0
      Queue:            0
        Log:            0
      Event:            0
      Alert:          261
Verdicts:
      Allow:        13263 ( 75.315%)
      Block:            0 (  0.000%)
    Replace:            0 (  0.000%)
  Whitelist:         4292 ( 24.373%)
  Blacklist:            0 (  0.000%)
     Ignore:            0 (  0.000%)
===============================================================================
Frag3 statistics:
        Total Fragments: 0
      Frags Reassembled: 0
               Discards: 0
          Memory Faults: 0
               Timeouts: 0
               Overlaps: 0
              Anomalies: 0
                 Alerts: 0
                  Drops: 0
     FragTrackers Added: 0
    FragTrackers Dumped: 0
FragTrackers Auto Freed: 0
    Frag Nodes Inserted: 0
     Frag Nodes Deleted: 0
===============================================================================
Stream5 statistics:
            Total sessions: 643
              TCP sessions: 285
              UDP sessions: 358
             ICMP sessions: 0
               IP sessions: 0
                TCP Prunes: 0
                UDP Prunes: 0
               ICMP Prunes: 0
                 IP Prunes: 0
TCP StreamTrackers Created: 285
TCP StreamTrackers Deleted: 285
              TCP Timeouts: 0
              TCP Overlaps: 0
       TCP Segments Queued: 7229
     TCP Segments Released: 7229
       TCP Rebuilt Packets: 1401
         TCP Segments Used: 7068
              TCP Discards: 95
                  TCP Gaps: 4
      UDP Sessions Created: 358
      UDP Sessions Deleted: 358
              UDP Timeouts: 0
              UDP Discards: 0
                    Events: 0
           Internal Events: 0
           TCP Port Filter
                   Dropped: 0
                 Inspected: 0
                   Tracked: 16321
           UDP Port Filter
                   Dropped: 0
                 Inspected: 51
                   Tracked: 358
===============================================================================
HTTP Inspect - encodings (Note: stream-reassembled packets included):
    POST methods:                         8
    GET methods:                          238
    HTTP Request Headers extracted:       261
    HTTP Request Cookies extracted:       94
    Post parameters extracted:            8
    HTTP response Headers extracted:      251
    HTTP Response Cookies extracted:      18
    Unicode:                              0
    Double unicode:                       0
    Non-ASCII representable:              0
    Directory traversals:                 0
    Extra slashes ("//"):                 37
    Self-referencing paths ("./"):        0
    HTTP Response Gzip packets extracted: 55
    Gzip Compressed Data Processed:       363978.00
    Gzip Decompressed Data Processed:     1132880.00
    Total packets processed:              8600
===============================================================================
SMTP Preprocessor Statistics
  Total sessions                                    : 0
  Max concurrent sessions                           : 0
===============================================================================
dcerpc2 Preprocessor Statistics
  Total sessions: 0
===============================================================================
SSL Preprocessor:
   SSL packets decoded: 1159
          Client Hello: 134
          Server Hello: 121
           Certificate: 89
           Server Done: 228
   Client Key Exchange: 77
   Server Key Exchange: 9
         Change Cipher: 214
              Finished: 0
    Client Application: 151
    Server Application: 59
                 Alert: 0
  Unrecognized records: 608
  Completed handshakes: 0
        Bad handshakes: 0
      Sessions ignored: 59
    Detection disabled: 0
===============================================================================
SIP Preprocessor Statistics
  Total sessions: 0
===============================================================================
Snort exiting
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are your alert settings in your snort.conf file? Also I would recommend running `tail -f <path to snort alert file>` when running snort, so you can see those alerts as they happen.

Comment: Thanks, I did tail -f and could see the alerts. I rebuilt on a different image and all is working.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, maybe you can try this one in terminal :

```
snort -i eth2 -A full
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer and explain it a bit more? When your reputation in Stackoverflow will be higher you will be able to post comments under the question. When you post an answer others might think the question already has valuable answers and might not pay attention to it anymore.